# How to test http error handlers in angular?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript

Here is sample of the code:

```
this.paymentTypesService.updatePaymentTypesOrder('cashout', newOrder).subscribe(() => {
  this.notificationsService.success(
    'Success!',
    `Order change saved successfully`,
    { showProgressBar: true, pauseOnHover: true, clickToClose: true }
  );
}, () => {
  this.notificationsService.error(
    'Error',
    `Order change save failed`,
    { showProgressBar: true, pauseOnHover: true, clickToClose: true }
  );
});
```

There is simple Http service behind the `paymentTypesService` methods... How should I test the error handler in such case?

Answer (score 0):

SOmething like this should work:

`spyOn(paymentTypesService, 'updatePaymentTypesOrder').and.returnValue(Observable.throw(new Error()))`